# Bar suspended by three vertical ropes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

A two dimensional homogeneous bar of mass *m* is suspended by three vertical inelastic ropes. The bar is horizontal and in equilibrium. One rope is fixed in the middle of the length of the bar (at point $P$) and the other two on the left and the right with equal distance from $P$, as shown in the image below.

[image]

**Question:** Is it possible to compute the tension of the three ropes?

Since the bar is in equilibrium, the forces sum to zero and the sum of the torques is zero as well. Since the actions of $\vec{F}_G$ and $\vec{F}_2$ pass $P$, they don't contribute to the torque around $P$. Since the actions of $\vec{F}_1$ and $\vec{F}_3$ have the same distance from $P$, computation of the torques around $P$ yields $F_1=F_3$. Since the sum of the forces is zero, we obtain
$$2F_1+F_2=F_G.$$
So, there are two indeterminates left, but just one equation. In order to compute $F_1, F_2$, I would need one more equation. But I have no idea, how to obtain the missing equation.

I search on the internet, but didn't find a reasonable solution. On a website there was a similar mock question with four ropes and the solution stated (without proof or reason) that the tension of each rope is 1/4 of the force of gravity. However, in general it is not true that the tension is just the amount of the force of gravity dived by the number of ropes. For, if you consider the problem above, with $\vec{F}_1$ and $\vec{F}_3$ acting  on different distances $r_1,r_3$ from $P$, than the torque equation around $P$ i.e. $F_1\cdot r_1=F_3\cdot r_3$ shows that $F_1$ and $F_3$ are different in this case.

Comment: I *think* it's not possible. Certainly there are two obvious extremes that work: $F_2=F_G\,,~F_1=F_3=0$ and $F_2=0\,,~F_1=F_3=F_G/2$.  Once there, it seems pretty clear that anything in between that matches equation in the OP works, too.

Comment: @march, agreed.  The problem is over-specified.

Comment: @march: But one can realize the constellation in the question by choosing ropes of  an apropriate material and little mass $m$. Then the ropes will have a definite tension and in mechanics, the result usually isn't random.

Comment: You can put the axis of rotation ($P$) anywhere, and get the same two equations: $F_1+F_2+F_3=F_g$ and $F_2=F_3$.

Comment: @ut813 I *think* the only way to make this completely specified (as it is *under*specified at the moment) is to undo part of the approximation and treat the ropes as stretchable, i.e., as springs with particular spring constants (and perhaps one even needs them to have mass, but I'm not sure of that). Only then are you giving the system the "freedom" to *adjust* to the situation.  I think what you'll find is that the ratio of the "tension" forces in the three ropes is related to the ratio of the spring constants (and it will be related to the moment arm, as well).

Comment: @Paul: No, this doesn't work. For example, let $P_1$ be the point where the left handed rope is fiaxed at the bar and let the distances between the ropes be each $r$. Then the torque around $P_1$ gives $r \cdot F_2 + 2r\cdot F_3 = r\cdot F_G$. Then substituting $F_1=F_3$ just yields again $2F_1+F_2=F_G$.

Comment: The problem is statically indeterminate.

Comment: I hypothesize, that roughly $F_i = \frac 13 F_G$, because gravity force induced pressure over bar cross-section area, must be equal to "local pressure" of tension force $F_i$ induced over "local area" $A_i$, which obviously has to be 1/3 in general case. But I can't prove it, just my "gut feeling".

Comment: @DavidWhite"over-specified"?

Comment: @DJohnM, yeah.  Only two ropes are needed to work out a solution.  That third rope will yield infinitely many solutions, as other commenters have pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

This is a canonical example of an underdefined problem (the number of unknowns (3 tensions) is less than the number of conditions (torque=0 and total force=0). You've tried to come up with a third condition $F_1 = F_3$, but this is not robust and -- most importantly -- it does not solve the issue. The actual issue is that the problem in question does not have a well-defined solution as long as you assume the ropes to be non-stretchable. Indeed, imagine you have attached the middle string after the side ones. Then, its tension is most likely zero. Conversely, if you've first hung the rod on the middle string, then the side ones don't really have to carry anything. In order to avoid this ambiguity, you need to assign finite elasticity  to the strings (i.e. replace them with springs). Then you will get the missing third condition and that will also make the problem well-defined.

In case you read Russian, this problem was described in detail in a book "Раз задача, два задача" by A. Buzdin, A. Zilberman, S. Krotov (ISBN 5-02-014401-0) on page 118.